# AD623-Unable to change gain or reference voltage

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

I have an air [flow sensor](https://www.idt.com/us/en/document/dst/fs1012-datasheet) (FS1012-1100NG) with expected differential output voltages ranging from -1mV to 20mV and I need to 1) know the precise value (mV) and gain to correlate V with airflow 2) make sure that value has long-term stability (order of days) and 3) end up with a voltage that makes the best use of my 12bit ADC.

I'm using an AD623 with a single supply (3.3V) with the FS1012 connected per the datasheet (see image).

- pins 1&8 Gain Resistor (I've tried 100ohm-1Mohm but no change in output/gain)
- pins 2&3 TP2+ and TP1+ (I've checked these and there is a differential voltage of about 2-3mV at max airflow)
- pins 4&7 Ground and 3.3V
- pin 5 Ref (Tested 0-3V using voltage divider, no change in output/offset)
- pin 6 Output (to digital multi-meter with ref to ground)

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better differential amplifier I should be using?
Thank you in advance!

[image: Basic Block Diagram for FS1012-1100]
[image: Amplifier Block Diagram]

Comment: Any INA with programmable gain shud work. BUT Vin MUST be within Vcm range near V+/2 so you do this with Rdivider pullup network.

Comment: Use an R network pack for best CMRR noise rejection

Comment: Does your AD632 share a common ground with your sensor?

Comment: @brhans Yes all grounds are common.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I'm focused on getting the hardware correct right now and then will look at the software side. I have an INA126PA and have reviewed the datasheet but I don't see what you are referring to. Any direction you could give would be awesome!

Comment: @Ryan, I see that you are following the datasheet's example of using a differential op-amp before the AD623. I was wondering why don't you just let FS0102's diff output go direct to AD623. In other words, no diff op-amp required. And I have the feeling that AD623 is a bit old, and newer and even cheaper Analog Devices ADC modules are around.

Comment: @tlfong01 The AD623 is the diff. amp. How would you recommend measuring 0-20mV?

Comment: @Ryan, my apologies. I am newbie enough not to know that 20mV is too small for AD623. Let me read the datasheet to correct my wrong idea about ADC. Thank you again for pointing out my careless mistake. Cheers.

Comment: So I googled and compared AD1248 (a common 24 bit ADC) with ADS623, with the following summary: (1) ADS1248 (24-bit ADC): Input range = –2.5V to +2.5V, PGA gain = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, Accuracy = 24 bits,

(2) ADS623 (don't know how many bits): Input range = -0.15 to +1.5V, Gain = 1 to 1000, Accuracy = 0.35%. My misunderstanding might be caused by the following: (a) AD623's accuracy is 0.35%, but ADS1248 is 24 bit accuracy, (b) ADC's input range is much wider than AD623. I must confess I have no experience with instrumentation amplifier. so I might miss something important, eg, noise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112100/discussion-between-ryan-and-tlfong01).

Comment: @tlfong01 the AD623 *is* the differential amp, it's not the ADC.

Answer (score 2):

INA126 specs for common mode range is undefined at Vs+=3.3, Vs-=0 yet it says works to Vs=3V I can see the Vcm only shifts down with Vs+ due to high side current source voltage drop.  So I take 3.3/5 x100% of the Fig 22 mean voltage of 1.6V. this equals 3.3/5*1.6= ≈1.0V rounded down.

- using 100000x more current than input bias current to minimize offset from input bias current
- we get a 4 resistor solution with no loss of differential input.  from Fig 14 Ib≈14 nA so you can make 1V with >1.4mA roughly even 1mA with this low impedance is OK.

**thus Rpu=2.3k, Rpd=1.0k I=3.3/ 3.3k=1mA , Vth= 1/3.3 x 3.3V=1.0V**. Pullup (pu) to 3.3V, Down(pd) to 0 V pref using lowest error tolerance if using gain=1000 to minimize DC out offset.

Then use a lower Zcm bias resistors for each INA input between Zsource and ZIn(INA)

### my preference

Use a 1.0 V LDO with RF cap and RC bias to both inputs at 1.0V. this gives better differential noise rejection and common mode line noise rejection. Using RC=<50ms and R= 50k, C=1uF

**Somehow you must to define your nominal input voltage and output if you want unipolar from 0V  or bipolar centred around midscale output**. TBD

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH6buT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Where are you seeing this on the data sheet? I have a limited power supply of 3.3V so Vcm cannot get 3.75V above the ref pin

Comment: Sorry let me correct it, I re-read spec

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I'm not quite sure I understand the significance of the 1mA current since the thermophiles in my flow sensor (FS1012) have a resistance of 200KOhm. I've changed the setup of my wires to make the ground for my sensor and ref pins the same at 1V (like I think you are indicating) to both up my common mode voltage and improve the swing range. Is this what you meant? Any chance you could include a diagram to clarify anything I missed.

Comment: Thanks for including the Pile specs of 200k

Comment: I've attempted your setup but the output doesn't change when I vary the gain or ref voltage even though the input measurably changes. I've added this additional figure to my OP to show maybe a thermopile is more of a voltage source and so the offset voltage should come before the sensor. When I do this the gain finally impacts the output but the range seems very limited to whatever ref voltage I choose. The range improves when Vref is the same as the CM voltage of the thermopile. Why is this? How can I improve the range to get as close to rail to rail as possible?

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I've concluded that a minimum offset voltage for both the reference and thermopile "virtual grounds" (aka TP1- and TP2-) needs to be +0.8V-1.0V above ground. The thermopile needs to be considered a voltage source and so the second figure in my OP is the basis for moving forward. I don't understand why this is but it is likely related to the topology of the In-Amp since ref directly tied to the gain shown in the block diagram for INA126. I also suspect there is a "deadzone" in the common mode graphs that is disregarded by using the term Vd/2. [image: Image from Spec Sheet for INA126]

I can say with confidence INA126 is the way to go and without @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I wouldn't have come to an answer. Thank you for your help!